# jquery: Update element offset top on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hope this isn't a duplicate question as I've been searching for some time for this issue and haven't found a clean solution yet. Maybe I'm just not searching correctly.

I have a navbar which has its position set to fixed trough javascript when it reaches the top of the viewport. I'm using jquery 1.11.3 to get offset().top of the element, however this value doesn't seem to update itself when the vertical height of the viewport changes.

For example, on an Android tablet with Chrome the address bar disappears, the 'resize' event is triggered but the `offset().top` of the element remains the same causing my navbar to remain static although it was scrolled past the top of the viewport and should be now fixed. I have also used a timeout to read the new value on resize but to no avail.

Is there some way to ask jquery to reconsider the viewport size so that I don't update my internal offset based on the new values? Or maybe this isn't the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem as you. On window resize, my element offset value was not change. In my case, my element was in fixed position. Maybe yours too? But if I scroll the page, the element offset changed. So In my case, I just put a fixed offset value to be use for my element.

Comment: Yes, it had fixed position. Since I could not find a good solution to this I just switched the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try implement this code in your window resize event

```
elementTop = $('#element').offset().top;
windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

if( elementTop - windowTop < 0) {
 // write your set fixed position code here
}
```

Comment: Ok, I guess the question is not very clear. $('#element').offset().top returns the same value before and after the resize event. When the address bar disappears, the distance to the top of the viewport is no longer the same but jquery says it is.

Comment: Ah ok now i got it, and i think issue can be flowing that when you have opened address bar it display over your content that is why after it disappear $('#element').offset().top remains same. I think you can try detect if it android tablet and in that case on first initial resize event automatically minus address bar height from taken $('#element').offset().top